# using Gatling, how can the statusInfo in the response be checked?

Tags: scala, gatling, scala-gatling

When making an http request using Gatling, the response has the java method getStatusInfo() which returns and object of type StatusType which has a getReasonPhrase() which returns a String.
I'd like to get that reasonPhrase from the response.
How do I do that?
I tried the code below but it complains about the statusInfo:

```
  /**
    * give the user access 
    *
    * @param session current gatling session
    * @return the serialized body
    */
  def giveAccess(token: String, store: String, testUserUsername: String): ChainBuilder = {
    exec(http("Give Access")
      .post(MY_SERVICE_URI)
      .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, token)
      .header(MyHeaders.STORE, store)
      .headers(defaultHeaders)
      .headers(additionalHeaders)
      .body(StringBody(session => preparePayLoadForGiving(session, testUserUsername)))
      .check(statusInfo.reasonPhrase.is(session => "reason"))
    )
  }
```

Comment: did not work. thanks

Comment: what do you get ?

Comment: i gave up... after reading the documentation i think it's not possible... i  just log the body

Answer (score 0):

I think the fix is to replace:

> statusInfo.reasonPhrase

by:

> status.reasonPhrase